# Alternative to gdal2tiles MapTiler for tiling a GTiff

Tags: geotiff-tiff, tiles

Right now I am trying to tile a GTiff into tiles to be used for e.g. Leaflet (so Mercator).

I played around with MapTiler and gdal2tiles. I am not entirely happy with both. Gdal2Tiles seems to pixelate the tiles, when I compare them to the tif. MapTiler cannot read the tif (I removed a band, MapTiler does not like that - also I want to be able to run the thing on a server, without GUI).

I also heard about TileMill, but TileMill seems to be deprecated.

So, I was wondering if there is any suitable alternative for tiling a GTiff?

BTW: the approach should be capable to tile a GeoTIFF with world-wide coverage.

Comment: Recognise that Mercator projection cannot be used for world-wide coverage. It is limited to a bit over 85N and 85S, and there is no polar coverage.

Comment: Give an example of source file and gdal2tiles command that leads to pixelated output

Answer (score 5):

GDAL natively now supports mbtiles and geopackages and does not rely on gdal2tiles.py  use GDAL_Translate or GDAL_WARP

However check out gdal2tiles_parallel.py it's awesome fast 
https://github.com/GitHubRGI/geopackage-python/blob/master/Tiling/gdal2tiles_parallel.py

Comment: Thanks for the hint to gdal2tiles_parallel, that looks very interesting. How would I create tiles fom a GTif using eiter GDAL_Translate or GDAL_WARP - compareable to gdal2tiles?

Comment: gdal2tiles_parallel.py is faster and adds all the zoom levels/overviews where gdal_translate and gdal_warp just do the lowest zoom level (equivalent 1:1)

Comment: @Robin See https://www.gdal.org/frmt_mbtiles.html
$ gdal_translate my_dataset.tif my_dataset.mbtiles -of MBTILES
$ gdaladdo -r average my_dataset.mbtiles 2 4 8 16

Answer (score 3):

You can try Qtiles - QGIS plugin to tile your tiff. See https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qtiles/ and http://gis-lab.info/qa/qtiles-eng.html

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @GeospatialInformationTech's answer, with [GDAL's native MBTiles support](https://www.gdal.org/frmt_mbtiles.html) you can do:

```
$ gdal_translate my_dataset.tif my_dataset.mbtiles -of MBTILES
$ gdaladdo -r average my_dataset.mbtiles 2 4 8 16
```

You can then use [mbutil](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil) to expand that MBTiles into files:

```
$ mb-util my_dataset.mbtiles tiles
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [rio-tiler](https://github.com/cogeotiff/rio-tiler). Powerful, dtype-independent, won't start type conversion or something unless explicitly stated. Founded on [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio.git), which written in Cython, so the tiling will be fast.

Example usage:

```
from rio_tiler.io import COGReader

with COGReader("my.tif") as image:
    img = image.tile(x, y, z) # read mercator tile z-x-y
```